# Error in change set with MasterDetail relationship even after relationship deleted

Tags: deployment, master-detail, change-set

I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot set sharingModel to ControlledByParent on a CustomObject without a MasterDetail relationship field

I've looked it up online and found out that it (likely) has to do with a masterdetail field, but I still don't understand what exactly is causing it, or -- more importantly -- HOW to narrow down what it is. Salesforce puts me over the edge sometimes with unhelpful/dead-end error messages.

I do not know what field it could be. There was one field that was on the object that was a lookup to another of the same type (a "Service Invoice" with a related "Followup Service Invoice" (same obj. type). I have removed this, as I no longer use it, and I am still getting this error. By removed, I do not just mean from the change set. I deleted the field altogether. How can I narrow down what is causing this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56948/discussion-on-question-by-natalie-spatharakis-error-in-change-set-with-masterdet).